# How do we get multiple values from a single django orm query?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

```
class Test(ModelBase):
     team = models.IntegerField(null=True)



id    created_at                           team
 1     2018-02-14 10:33:46.307214+05:30    1
 2     2018-02-24 10:41:40.307681+05:30    1
 3     2018-03-14 12:00:02.748088+05:30    1
 4     2018-03-12 18:05:33.598297+05:30    3
 5     2018-03-12 18:04:00.694774+05:30    3
 6     2018-04-14 11:24:48.554993+05:30    3
 7     2018-04-14 11:42:27.442441+05:30    3
 8     2018-05-11 15:53:21.528813+05:30    3
 9     2018-05-08 15:49:58.684201+05:30    3
```

How can we get from a single query current month & team = 3 count, last month & team = 3 count?

Comment: Can you post model class?

Comment: Sure I will add the model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) which allows to perform query with OR conditions:

```
current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
first_day_of_current_month = datetime.datetime.now().replace(day=1)
last_month = (first_day_of_current_month - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).month

Test.objects.filter(Q(created_at__month=current_month, team=3)|Q(created_at__month=last_month, team=3))
```

Comment: Can we get for each month from this query?

Comment: With the above query we are filtering all together. But can we do it for current_month, last_month from one query?

Comment: @BharatBittu you can add `order_by('created_at')` This will sort output by date.

Comment: from the above query we get a total count for current month and last month. To again filter for one month, we will have to do a for loop. But using from the same query can we get for this month, last month count separately?

Comment: I got the same error for this query before too.                                 
Cannot resolve keyword 'month' into field. Join on 'created_at' not permitted

Comment: Even if we run the above query we will still have to loop. Can we not get count directly from same query for each month?

Comment: @BharatBittu sorry cannot help you with this.

Comment: That's okay :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: something like this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/  pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(below_5=below_5).annotate(above_5=above_5)

Answer (score 1):

You just can filter with chain queryset. Just get your `current_month` and `last_month` (it should be integer) and

```
Test.objects.filter(created_at__month__in=[current_month, last_month], team=3)
```

Comment: How do we get for each month after running this query?

Comment: just use like @neverwalkaloner

Comment: You don't need chaining, just put both conditions in one call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TruncMonth` to get data filtered by each month. You can then gen first and last index value.

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
from django.db.models import Sum

queryset = Test.objects.all().annotate(
             month=TruncMonth('created_at')).values('month').annotate(
             number=Sum('team'))
```

Comment: No, I want output like for this month, total count for team 3 is 5